# How to make transparent label in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a label which is on a picture. So I want to make transparent back color of the label. When I make backcolor property of the label to transparent. The picture doesn't showed through the text box back color. The backcolor gets color of the form.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fskY2.png)

Comment: Thats how it works - Transparent means use whatever back color of the parent.  There is no concept of one control being "in front of" another one. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of a Lable is *inherited* from its container Background.

You can set a different Parent Container using the [`[Control].Controls.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) method, which sets the Parent property to the new Container (you could also modify the `.Parent` property directly).

You can re-define your Label's Parent in the Form constructor (the `Public Sub New()` of a Form - insert the code after `InitializeComponent()`) or in the `Form.Load()` event handler.
Here I'm showing both, pick one:

```
Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    PictureBox1.Controls.Add(Label1)
    'Re-define the Label.Location if required
    Label1.Location = New Point(0, 0)
End Sub
```

The same thing in the Form.Load() event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Controls.Add(Label1)
End Sub
```

As an alternative, you could use the PictureBox `.Paint()` event's `e.Graphics` to simply Draw the same Text.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Using TextBrush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("BITS Registration ID", Me.Font, TextBrush, New Point(5, 5))
    End Using
End Sub
```